# Received a make error while building warp-ctc pytorch

Tags: python, cmake, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to build https://github.com/SeanNaren/warp-ctc.git on Google Colab, following [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Hramchenko/Handwritting/blob/master/colab_install_deps.ipynb#scrollTo=LMS9vDgDxnIy) notebook. I am using these commands on Colab:

```
!git clone https://github.com/SeanNaren/warp-ctc.git;\
cd warp-ctc;\
mkdir build;\
cd build;\
cmake ..;\
make;
```

but I am receiving an error building it:

```
[-11%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/src/warpctc_generated_ctc_entrypoint.cu.o
/content/drive/My Drive/simple_hwr/warp-ctc/src/ctc_entrypoint.cu(1): error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

/content/drive/My Drive/simple_hwr/warp-ctc/src/ctc_entrypoint.cu(1): error: expected a ";"

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00000191_00000000-13_ctc_entrypoint.compute_70.cpp1.ii".
CMake Error at warpctc_generated_ctc_entrypoint.cu.o.cmake:279 (message):
  Error generating file /content/drive/My
  Drive/simple_hwr/warp-ctc/build/CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/src/./warpctc_generated_ctc_entrypoint.cu.o


CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/build.make:220: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/src/warpctc_generated_ctc_entrypoint.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/src/warpctc_generated_ctc_entrypoint.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:146: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc/issues/49#issuecomment-344307435) documents an apparent fix for this issue, which also affects the original [warp-ctc](https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc) repository:

> [...] the ctc_entrypoint.cu file needs to be a symlink. So, go to src dir and run:
>
> ```
> rm ctc_entrypoint.cu
> ln -s ctc_entrypoint.cpp ctc_entrypoint.cu
> ```

Then, re-run `make`, which should resolve the issue.